# Grails unit test fails on @PostConstruct

Tags: unit-testing, grails, dependencies, postconstruct

Have a `@PostConstruct` in the service to ensure that the dependencies have been set up. Dependencies are set in `resources.groovy`. Unit test fails on `@PostConstruct` asserts. Tried setting up the dependencies manually in `setUpSpec` to no avail. Even without a `@TestFor`, `ServiceUnitTestMixin` kicks in and merrily chokes on `@PostConstruct`.
Opened a defect [GRAILS-11878](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11878) which was closed promptly with an advice to use `@FreshRuntime` and `doWithSpring`. If they actually bothered to try, they'd have gotten the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'grails.spring.BeanBuilder$ConfigurableRuntimeBeanReference$WrappedPropertyValue@2cce10bc' with class 'grails.spring.BeanBuilder$ConfigurableRuntimeBeanReference$WrappedPropertyValue' to class 'java.util.Collection'
```

Service under test:

```
@Transactional
class MovieRipIndexService {

    Collection<String> genres

    Collection<String> includes

    @PostConstruct
    void postConstruct() {
        notEmpty(genres as Collection, 'Genres must not be null or empty.')
        notEmpty(includes as Collection, 'Includes must not be null or empty.')
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@FreshRuntime
@TestFor(MovieRipIndexService)
class MovieRipIndexServiceSpec extends Specification {

    def doWithSpring = {
        serviceHelper(ServiceHelper)

        service.genres = serviceHelper.genres
        service.includes = serviceHelper.includes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring support in unit tests is rather minimal, and the `ApplicationContext` that's active doesn't really go through any of the lifecycle phases that it would in a running app, or even during initialization of integration tests. You get a lot of functionality mixed into your class when using `@TestFor` and/or `@Mock`, but it's almost entirely faked out so you can focus on unit testing the class under test.

I tried implementing `org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean` just now and that worked, so you might get further with that.`@Transactional` will also be ignored - the "database" is a `ConcurrentHashMap`, so you wouldn't get far with that anyway.

If you need real Spring behavior, use integration tests. Unit tests are fast and convenient but only useful for a fairly limited number of scenarios.

Comment: I actually don't need Spring for these tests which's why I didn't write an integration test. However, as I wrote in my question, even if I just instantiate the service class (new) and set the dependencies myself, ServiceUnitTestMixin kicks in and runs PostConstruct. If it didn't all'd be good. It seems like a bug that it does that even without a TestFor annotation. I don't want to implement InitializingBean interface because Spring recommends not to use it since a couple of years back. It'd be a step backward.